# Abstract Class vs Interfaces with example

Tags: java, inheritance

So I am trying to understand the differences between Abstract Class and Interfaces. I know this is a well covered topic but I wrote some code to see if I can get a better idea of the concept. Let me know please if I am on the right track as far as how I am reasoning the differences out.

My understanding is that I would use an abstract class when there are core similarities between objects/classes. In my example here, I use Quadrilaterals as my abstract class. This is a 4-sided figure (speaking in a two-dimensional sense). This means that I can create Rectangle and Square objects by extending this abstract class and take advantage of the 4-sidedness(?) of the abstract class. Therefore, these classes will inherit that core property. So an abstract class may primarily be used to write common code to reflect these core properties. So in essence, my abstract class DEFINES the derived classes (Rectangle and Square). Right so far?

The Interface is used when there are also commonalties, but the difference is that the interface, unlike the abstract class, does NOT define the class that uses it. It merely has abstract methods (contracts, in a sense) that must be used if the interface is implemented about a particular class. The purpose of this is to use common methods in somewhat similar classes to highlight similar features of those classes. Like getArea() and getPerimeter() of all Shapes, whether Quadrilateral or not. Right?

In my example, I implemented the method getNumberofSidesForQuadrilaterals to return the number of sides for the Quadrilaterals. This will always return 4. I could have used this method in the interface instead but it would be pointless since that would result in me having to call the method on an object that we already know is 4 sided (for each 4 sided object created) Would seem like a waste of time. Am I right? close, way off? Added examples with object references (to show relationships) are welcome.

```
package abstractex;

/**
 *
 * 
 */


 interface Shapes{     

    public double getPerimeter();
    public double getArea();

}

    public abstract class Quadrilaterals implements Shapes{

    double base,height; 
    double sides;


    public int getNumberofSidesForQuadrilaterals(){

        final int sides = 4;
        System.out.println(sides);
        return sides;
    }

 }

class Rectangle extends Quadrilaterals  {

    public Rectangle(double base, double height) {
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter(){

        double r = 1;

        double perimeter = (2 * base) + (2 * height);

        System.out.println("The perimeter of the Rectangle is " + perimeter);

        return perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){

        double area = base * height;

        System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle is " + area);


        return base * height;
    }

}  

 class Square extends Quadrilaterals {


    public Square(double base, double height) {
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter(){

        double perimeter = base * 4;

        if (base == height)
        {
            System.out.println("The perimeter of the Square is " + perimeter);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The base and height of the square must be equal");
        }

        return perimeter;

     }   

    @Override
    public double getArea(){

        double area = base * base;

         if (base == height)
        {
            System.out.println("The area of the Square is " + area);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The base and height of the square must be equal");
        }

        return area;
    }

 }

class Circle implements Shapes{

    double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter(){

        double perimeter = 2*radius*Math.PI;

        System.out.println("The perimeter of the Circle is " + perimeter);

        return perimeter;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){

        double area =  Math.PI*radius*radius; 

        System.out.println("The area of the Circle is " + area);
        return area;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle c = new Rectangle(5,2);
        c.getPerimeter();
        c.getArea();
        c.getNumberofSidesForQuadrilaterals();


        Square d = new Square(5,5);
        d.getPerimeter();
        d.getArea();
        d.getNumberofSidesForQuadrilaterals();


        Circle e = new Circle(5);
        e.getArea();
        e.getPerimeter();


    }

 }
```

Output :

The perimeter of the Rectangle is 14.0

The area of the Rectangle is 10.0

4

The perimeter of the Square is 20.0

The area of the Square is 25.0

4

The area of the Circle is 78.53981633974483

The perimeter of the Circle is 31.41592653589793

Comment: Note: the correct term for a four-sided shape is quadrilateral.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question may be a bit unclear, as it is somewhat hidden in the last paragraph. 
Apart from that, there is no real difference between abstract classes and interfaces with respect to the names of the functions. The set of functions defined in a class (and inherited)  *is* the interface. Interfaces define a *contract* in the same way abstract classes do. The difference is that abstract classes can define behavior, and interfaces (could*) not. (*they can now with `default`). And classes can implement multiple interfaces, but only extend a single class. While `getNumberOfSides()` would be a better choice for your `Shape` interface, `getNumberofSidesForQuadlaterals()` could fit in some interace as well. Even though the result should always be 4, in theory the way you calculate the number could be implemented differently, and may even be implemented by a non-shape class. The latter would not be possible if you would define it in an Abstract class.

In the end it all boils down to how you are going to use the code. If you have 5 different ways of calculating the number of sides of a 
4-sided shape, then an interface might be a good idea. Otherwise, probably not.

(Also, use singular form for the name of your abstract class/interface.  A `Circle` is-a `Shape`, not `Shapes`. And for `Square` you should only be able to specify the length of one side, not the `base` and `height`. Otherwise your square may actually become a rectangle.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm trying to have a prepared answer incase this is asked of me in an interview. So the question really is, what is the main difference between the two.

Comment: @IGJ Did my answer address that, or do you need to know more?

Comment: If you can offer a little more explanation. It got a little confusing when you said "Interfaces define a contract in the same way abstract classes do. The difference is that abstract classes can define behavior, and interfaces (could*) not. (*they can now with default)." Perhaps real world examples?

Comment: Any real world example on the differences would be great.

Comment: The contract is defined by the function. The name, the return type, _what_ the function is supposed to do, not _how_ it does it. What part exactly is confusing?